# Same or different name for the field in a JSON-formatted input for an API that can take 2 different formats

Tags: rest

I have an API that takes an input like

```
{ 'fileContent': 'base64-encoded file here' }
```

I would like to accept also an URI with the file content.

Should I use the same fileContent field name, for example:

```
{ 'fileContent': 'https://example.com/filename' }
```

and then decode the base64 or download the URI in my code, or use a different field name, for example:

```
{ 'fileUri': 'https://example.com/filename' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a different field name is more flexible and makes your code less buggy when checking the field contents.